# docker nginx reverse proxy 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to use nginx as reverse proxy for my remote home automation access.

My infrastructure yaml looks like follows:

```yaml
# /infrastructure/docker-compose.yaml
version: '3'

services:
  proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy:alpine
    container_name: proxy
    networks:
      - raspberry_network
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    environment:
      - ENABLE_IPV6=true
      - DEFAULT_HOST=${RASPBERRY_IP}
    volumes:
      - ./proxy/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./proxy/vhost.d:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - ./proxy/html:/usr/share/nginx/html
      - ./proxy/certs:/etc/nginx/certs
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    restart: always

networks:
  raspberry_network:
```

My yaml containing the app configuration looks like this:

```yaml
# /apps/docker-compose.yaml

version: '3'

services:
  homeassistant:
    container_name: home-assistant
    image: homeassistant/raspberrypi4-homeassistant:stable
    volumes:
      - ./homeassistant:/config
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
    environment:
      - 'TZ=Europe/Berlin'
      - 'VIRTUAL_HOST=${HOMEASSISTANT_VIRTUAL_HOST}'
      - 'VIRTUAL_PORT=8123'
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          memory: 250M
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      - infrastructure_raspberry_network
    ports:
      - '8123:8123'

networks:
  infrastructure_raspberry_network:
    external: true
```

Via portainer I validated that both containers are contected to the same network. However, when accessing my local IP of the raspberry pi 192.168.0.10 I am receiving "503 Service Temporarily Unavailable".

Of course when I try accessing my app via the virtual host domain xxx.xxx.de it neither works.

Any idea what the issue might be? Or any ideas how to further debug this?

Comment: `Or any ideas how to further debug this?` => `docker-compose logs homeassistant` to find out why it is not running or having a hard time to answer requests.

Comment: HA is running. I can go the the application by typing in the ip address of the raspberry pi

Comment: Have you checked error log at `/var/log/nginx/error.log` in the nginx container ?

Answer (score 4):

1. You need to specify the correct `VIRTUAL_HOST` in the backends environment variable and make sure that they're on the same network (or docker bridge network)
2. Make sure that any containers that specify `VIRTUAL_HOST` are running before the `nginx-proxy` container runs. With `docker-compose`, this can be achieved by adding to `depends_on` config of the `nginx-proxy` container

Comment: 1. I did correctly. I am pretty sure.
2. You mean that at first the app needs to start and then the nginx-proxy container?

Comment: Yes @WorkoutBuddy